# what does "der Schtritzi" mean in Brecht?

Tags: dialect, regional

Brecht 1970 Furcht und Elend des Dritten Reiches (Suhrkamp, 1970), pages 95--96:

> DER BAUER Akkurat so.  Die sind nicht für die Bauern und die Bauern sind nicht für die.  Mein Korn soll ich abliefern, und das Viehfutter soll ich teuer kaufen.  Damit der Schtritzi Kanonen kaufen kann.

From the immediate context, Schtritzi seems to refer to some aspect of the Third Reich authorities, leadership, military, etc.
But I did not find the word in
https://www.wordreference.com/deen/Schtritzi
or
https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de.

From the bigger context it seems that perhaps "der Schtritzi" is the proper name of their ox.
The farmer and his wife complain that the Third Reich's four-year plan requires them to starve their animals.
On page 95 we have:

> DER BAUER ...  Der Herrgott will nie nicht, daß eine Kreatur hungert. Und sobald sie hungert, schreit sie, und ich kann nicht hören, daß eine Sau schreit auf meinem Hof von wegen Hunger.

> DIE BÄUERIN ... Und der Herr Pfarrer hat gesagt: Du sollst dem Ochsen, der da drischet, nicht das Maul verbinden. Da hat er angedeutet, daß wir ruhig unser Vieh füttern können.

So with this interpretation he would be saying, in effect:

> I am supposed to sell my grain crop cheap and then buy feed at a high price, all so that my poor ox Schtrizi will pay for their cannons.

But finally, https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/striezi-der/ gives

> 1. Gauner, Herumtreiber, Strolch
> 2. Zuhälter

whereas Duden Universalwörterbuch 2011, page 1700 gives

> Strietzel, der; ... (landschaft.) ... 1. längliches, meist geflochtenes Hefegebäck ... 2. frecher Bursche, Lausbub.

The Bayrisches seems closest to what the farmer would mean, then:

> ... so that son of a _____ing pimp can buy weapons.

And he's referring to the Big Shot, without naming him.

Thus the answer, I think, is that Brecht uses a southern German word
whose precise form and sense
is unknown to
https://www.wordreference.com/deen/Schtritzi,
to
https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de, and to
the big Duden.
Even though Duden contains many southern and Swiss-German words, such as "grüetzi."

Does this sound correct?

Additional evidence:
https://www.alemannische-seiten.de/alemannisch/lexikon.php?le=4493

> Strolch (kleiner Lausbub)
>
> Südbadisch
>
> Strietzi, Strizi, Schtrizi, Luser
>
> Hinweis: Der Ausdruck Strietzi bzw. Strolch bezeichnet ursprünglich einen Landstreicher, Vagabunden, später dann eher einen Spitzbuben im Sinne von wilder kleiner Junge oder Schlingel.

Comment: You correctly identified the meaning of the word. It is obviously attributed to Hitler.

Comment: The play is from 1938, not 1970.

Comment: 1970 is the date of the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already solved this puzzle I guess.

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Strizzi) also calls it "Strizzi" and lists the synonyms

1 Strolch, Bengel
2 Zuhälter, Spitzbube
3 Bengel, Lausbub, Spitzbube, ungezogener Junge

"Strizzi" is also in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Strizzi) and in Grimm's [Deutschem Wörterbuch](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB&lemid=S52392#0).

In the Brecht play, it refers to Göring or Hitler of course.

Comment: Your links also trace the word to Italian. Thus https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strizzi and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strizzare#Italian

Comment: Of [note](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strizzi): "Des Weiteren werden in Südtirol die Österreicher allgemein oft pejorativ...als Strizzi bezeichnet." I'm sure I have heard that usage before, and not only from Tyrolians.

Comment: I doubt that it refers to Göring. He was responsible for the air force.